# django two ForeignKeys to same model - admin error

Tags: python, django

I have a Profiles app that has a model called profile, i use that model to extend the django built in user model without subclassing it.

**models.py**

```
class BaseProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='owner',primary_key=True)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='supervisor', null=True, blank=True)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Profile(BaseProfile):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}'s profile". format(self.user)
```

**admin.py**

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile

class NewUserAdmin(NamedUserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline ]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, NewUserAdmin)
```

admin

**the error is**

```
<class 'profiles.admin.UserProfileInline'>: (admin.E202) 'profiles.Profile' has more than one ForeignKey to 'authtools.User'.
```

obviously i want to select a user to be a supervisor to another user. I think the relationship in the model is OK, the one that's complaining is admins.py file. Any idea ?

Comment: Add related_name to user

Comment: tried that did not work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use multiple inline admin.

When you have a model with multiple ForeignKeys to the same parent model, you'll need specify the `fk_name` attribute in your inline admin:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    fk_name = "user"

class SupervisorProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    fk_name = "supervisor"

class NewUserAdmin(NamedUserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline, SupervisorProfileInline]
```

Django has some documentation on dealing with this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-a-model-with-two-or-more-foreign-keys-to-the-same-parent-model

Comment: fk_name = 'user' in UserProfileInline is what fixed it for me, i don't need to add another SupervisorProfileInline as i just needed a drop down to all users i select one as a supervisor...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I have just tested to be working

```
class Task(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='task_owner')
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='task_assigned_to')
```

In admin.py

```
class TaskInLine(admin.TabularInLine):
    model = User

@admin.register(Task)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['owner', 'assignee']
    inlines = [TaskInLine]
```

Comment: i have made a similar example and it does work, my problem is the admin interface and that error

Comment: @Bob Ezuba the problem Hakim has is the opposite. In your example, you won't be able to create a UserAdmin with an Inline admin with model Task.